# Lead Converted BY

Tags: reporting

How can I report on who converted a lead? I tried using the reprot type 'Leads with Leads with converted lead information but it doesnt have any field for "converted by" information. 
we do not assign leads so I cannot use that field to determine anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Lead History report, and filter on "Field/Event" equals "Lead Converted." The Edited By column shows who converted the lead, and Edit Date shows the time of conversion.